# what the difference between sizeof..(typename) and sizeof..(parameter) in variadic template c++

Tags: c++

Whats the difference between `sizeof..(typename)` and `sizeof..(parameter)`  in a variadic template in c++?

In cpp primer 5th, I can't understand the difference:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(const T &t, const Args &... rest)
{
    std::cout << "sizeof...(Args)=" << sizeof...(Args) << "  sizeof...(rest)=" << sizeof...(rest) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    double d = 3.14;
    string s = "how";

    foo(i, s, 42, d); /// sizeof...(Args)=3  sizeof...(rest)=3
    foo(s, 42, "hi"); /// sizeof...(Args)=2  sizeof...(rest)=2
    foo(d, s);        /// sizeof...(Args)=1  sizeof...(rest)=1
    foo("hi");        /// sizeof...(Args)=0  sizeof...(rest)=0
    foo(i, s, s, d);  /// sizeof...(Args)=3  sizeof...(rest)=3

    while (1)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof...(rest)` counts the number of arguments (not including the first). `sizeof...(Args)` counts the number of their types. There is no difference on the result.

Comment: so what means about   number of their types?  At the beginning,i sugge means type like int,string ,but the ouput tell me not.

Comment: @layty "At the beginning,i sugge means type like int,string ,but the ouput tell me not." i dont understand what you mean by that. Do you miss the "not including the first" part? When you call eg `foo(d,s);` then `Args....` is only `std::string` because the double is already `T`

Comment: @layty if you remove the first template parameter `T`, then `Args...` is all arguments

Comment: @layty The number of types in the pack `Args` - 3 in case of `string, int, double`.

Comment: @L.F in case of `foo<string,int,double>`, `sizeof...(Args)` is 2 not 3. I suspect that this is OPs misunderstanding, but not sure

Comment: @idclev463035818 I meant to say `Args = <string, int, double>`, but yeah that's a little bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof...` operator gives the number of arguments in a parameter pack, and works for both template parameter packs (like `Args`) and function parameter packs (like `rest`). A function parameter pack always has the same count as the template parameter pack(s) used in declaring its type, for each specialization of the function template.